# It does not trigger any errors when apply the Nil-Coalescing operator on a none optional variable

Tags: swift, operators, option-type

> The nil-coalescing operator **(a ?? b)** unwraps an optianl a if it contains a value, or returns a default value b if a is nil. The expression a is always of an optional type.
>
> The Nil-Coalescing operator is shorthand for the code below
>
> **a != nil ? a! : b**

I've then tried the following test code snippet

```
//First
let a: Int = 3, b: Int = 4
a ?? b // No error
```

&

```
//Second
let a: Int = 3, b: Int = 4
a != nil ? a! : b //Triggers an error: value of type 'int' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed
```

**Question :**

Why the Compiler didn't give an error for the first code snippet while yelling an error for the second one?  Ain't they are same?

Many Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nil-coalescing operator

```
public func ??<T>(optional: T?, @autoclosure defaultValue: () throws -> T)  rethrows -> T
```

takes an *optional* a the first operand. So `a ?? b` and `a != nil ? a! : b` are equivalent provided that `a` is an optional.

That is not the case in your example

```
let a: Int = 3, b: Int = 4
a ?? b
```

The first operand `a` is not an optional. However, the compiler  can
"wrap" a non-optional value `T` into an optional `T?` in order
to match a function or operator. For example, in

```
func foo(x: Int?) { }
foo(3)
```

the argument `3` is wrapped into an `Int?`.

In your case, the expression is equivalent to

```
Optional<Int>.Some(a) ?? b
```

which is equivalent to

```
Optional<Int>.Some(a) != nil ? Optional<Int>.Some(a)! : b
```

However, the compiler is not so smart to recognize that 
`Optional<Int>.Some(a)` cannot be `nil`.